# Best way for uploading or downloading images in ios . FTP vs HTTP

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, nsdata, image-uploading

Best way for upload or download images in ios?
in ios I can upload images and upload images on server by via ftp. I also saw many person use HTTP post methods for upload or download image in shape of NSData.

so which method is fast and secure?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is the better choice because port 80 is almost always open while port 21 is often closed in business settings.

Answer (score 1):

Neither are faster or more secure for your IOS app. In general FTP is not the most secure technology to be running on your server (sFTP is better), so many people prefer not to run FTP servers, and therefore have to use HTTP for uploads (as Zaph says, on many firewalls, FTP is not even allowed by default for this reason).

But using HTTP for uploads that requires code on your server to handle HTTP POST and put the files in the correct location. The fact that you are writing this code potentially makes it safer: you can validate the incoming data, make sure it is the right size and filetype and take account of any user bandwidth or storage limits.

You don't use HTTP post to download images, but HTTP GET. That doesn't require you to use anything special on the server, and HTTP server can serve it.

Unless you have a good reason not to, I'd suggest using HTTP. A good reason might be that you're integrating your app with an existing FTP service.